# Increase performance of synchronized horizontal scrolling with React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a grid which has synchronized horizontal scrolling between different sections (for example header and then multiple sections of the table below), so that if they scroll horizontally each section will scroll with it and stay in sync utilizing a redux state that holds the scroll position. The following solution is working, but there is noticeable lag between scrolling in one section and the others updating. I want to see if there's anyway to decrease this lag (eliminating it probably is unlikely). This is the general structure I have now:

```
class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleScrollChange = this.handleScrollChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleScrollChange(scrollPos) {
    // dispatches update to redux
    this.props.actions.updateScrollPosition(scrollPos)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {_.map(this.props.sections, (elem, i) => (
        <GridSection
          key={elem.id}
          scrollPosition={this.props.scrollPosition}
          onScrollHandler={this.handleScrollChange}
        />
      ))}
    )
  }
}

class GridSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.gridPanel.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
    this.gridPanel.scrollLeft = this.props.scrollPosition
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.scrollPosition !== this.props.scrollPosition) {
      this.gridPanel.scrollLeft = this.props.scrollPosition
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.gridPanel.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  handleScroll(ev) {
    if (typeof this.props.onScrollHandler !== 'function') return
    this.props.onScrollHandler(ev.target.scrollLeft)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={node => (this.gridPanel = node)}>
        // other shit here
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Naturally the actual thing is alot more complex then this and there is most likely some other performance issues, but my scrolling is very laggy.  Does anyone have some suggestions on improving performance here?

Comment: hey @Evan, did you manage to solve this? I have created a hook to sync scroll in between two elements. It is smooth, with no glitches, but sometimes on element bounces a little bit on scroll start. In other words, when I start the scroll, depending on the speed of the scroll, one element slightly delays a bit, then it syncs again...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using some kind of debouncing for scroll handlers, I also recently solved a similar problem by taking advantage of `requestAnimationFrame` to ensure only updating when the UI is ready.

```
handleScrollChange(scrollPos) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.props.actions.updateScrollPosition(scrollPos)
  });
}
```

Comment: Would I debounce handlers at the Grid level or the GridSection level?

Comment: You'll want to debounce as early in the stack as possible to maximize performance gains. You attached the scroll handler to GridSection, so it should be something like `this.gridPanel.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(this.handleScroll))`

Comment: @JoshuaManns if you debounce on a scroll callback, it will only occur after the scrolling is over.